# Prove that $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^c f(x)dx + \int_c^b f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Prove that $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^c f(x)dx + \int_c^b f(x)dx$

Note that $c$ need not belong to $(a, b)$

And $f(x)$ is a continuous function.

All ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Let

$$F(t)=\int_a^tf(x)dx+\int_t^bf(x)dx$$
then by the fundamental theorem of analysis we have
$$F'(t)=f(t)-f(t)=0$$
hence $F$ is a constant and we have
$$\forall c,\quad F(c)=F(a)=\int_a^bf(x)dx$$

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a continuous function so it has an antiderivative function. Let's note it $F$. So $F'=f$.

By the definition, we have $\int\limits_a^bf(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a)$

So $\int\limits_a^cf(x)\,dx+\int\limits_c^bf(x)\,dx=F(c)-F(a)+F(b)-F(c)=F(b)-F(a)=\int\limits_a^bf(x)\,dx$